Callback function from IFRAME javascript to google colab
So im learning google colab and ive encountered a problem, running my code in google colab, im openning a server and using IFRAME to see my website, the issue im trying to solve is when selecting a json file and clicking upload i want the file to be uploaded to my notebook local memory , my index.html file has a callback function:
<script>
        function uploadJson() {
           google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('notebook.uploadJSON', [file.name, content], {})
...
....

in colab itself i have registared the function :
output.register_callback('notebook.uploadJSON', upload_json)

which is under the function :
def upload_json(filename, content): ...

the issue im experiencing in the console is google is not defined and basically the callback not working.
ive read that callback might encounter problems when using iframe etc, anyone knows the reason or how to fix it? ive also tried to inject these function from cells in colab without using iframe and that kinda worked but then ive encountered other problems with css and js files not working
from google.colab import output
import IPython
from IPython.display import display, IFrame
import json
import os
import requests
import time


def upload_json(filename, content):
    data = json.loads(content)
    filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
    print(f"File '{filename}' has been saved successfully in the Colab folder.")
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        first_key = next(iter(data))
        print(f"First item in the JSON: {first_key}: {data[first_key]}")
    elif isinstance(data, list) and len(data) > 0:
        print(f"First item in the JSON: {data[0]}")
    else:
        print("The JSON file is empty or has an unexpected structure.")

output.register_callback('notebook.uploadJSON', upload_json)

# Function to download files from Firebase Storage
def download_file_from_firebase(bucket_name, file_name, local_path):
    url = f'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{bucket_name}/o/{file_name}?alt=media'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(local_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f'File {file_name} downloaded to {local_path}.')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to download {file_name}. Status code: {response.status_code}')

# Download necessary files
bucket_name = 'KEY.com'
file_names = [
    'index.html',
    'TeamGraph.html',
    'glossary.html',
    'notifications.html',
    'style.css',
    'KEY.json',
    'app.js',
    'notifications.js'
]

for file_name in file_names:
    download_file_from_firebase(bucket_name, file_name, file_name)

# List downloaded files
print("Downloaded files:", os.listdir())

# Serve the downloaded HTML files from Colab
time.sleep(2)
os.chdir('/content')
get_ipython().system_raw('python3 -m http.server 8000 &')

# Get the server URL
server_url = output.eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(8000)")

# Function to display an HTML file in an iframe
def display_html(filename):
    display(IFrame(src=f"{server_url}/{filename}", width='100%', height='600px'))

# Display the initial HTML file
display_html('index.html')

and thats the code in my index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JSON Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button-container">
        <a href="index.html" class="nav-button" id="btnIndex">JSON Upload</a>
        <a href="glossary.html" class="nav-button" id="btnGlossary">Glossary</a>
        <a href="TeamGraph.html" class="nav-button" id="btnTeamGraph">Team Stats</a>
        <a href="notifications.html" class="nav-button" id="btnNotifications">Notifications</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Upload JSON File</h2>
        <form id="jsonUploadForm">
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".json">
            <button type="button" id="uploadButton" onclick="uploadJson()">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function uploadJson() {
            console.log("uploadJson function called"); // Debugging statement
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            const file = fileInput.files[0];

            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    const content = event.target.result;
                    console.log("File content:", content); // Debugging statement
                    google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('notebook.uploadJSON', [file.name, content], {})
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log('Upload successful:', response);
                            alert('Upload successful');
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('Invoke function error:', error);
                            alert('Invoke function error: ' + error);
                        });
                };
                reader.onerror = function(event) {
                    console.error("Error reading file:", event.target.error);
                    alert("Error reading file: " + event.target.error);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            } else {
                alert('No file selected');
            }
        }

        // Disable the button for the current page
        const currentPage = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
        document.querySelector(`a[href="${currentPage}"]`).classList.add('active');
        document.querySelector(`a[href="${currentPage}"]`).disabled = true;
    </script>
</body>
</html>



https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js doesn't provide the global google property - perhaps you read the documentation poorly
